# Can I use exclusively declarative automation to merge records?

Tags: visual-workflow, duplicate-management, merge

I am working to build an automated process that will find two records that meet a set of criteria and merge the two records.

It seems like in a perfect world, there would be a pink "Merge records" element for that DML statement (which I understand to be an update followed by a delete operation).

Since there's not, I looked to create a DuplicateRecordSet record and two DuplicateRecordItem records connecting the two accounts I've queried.  I can get that far, no problem.

But I haven't been able to find a way to use Flow to then process the merge between those two duplicate record items.  I was hoping that at the most code-reliant, I'd be able to use an Apex Action to do so... but it seems like there aren't easy ways to code in the merge functionality without needing a UI component.

The latest attempt I've made has been just to pass the records I wanted merged into an Apex action like this one (but without the queries to identify the records):
https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/explain-the-use-of-dml-merge-operation-in-salesforce/

It just seems strange that I can't use DuplicateRecordSets or DuplicateRecordItems or any declarative functionality to accomplish this task.  Has anyone done this more simply and easily?

Comment: Could you be bring in some more clarity in the question? Like where exactly are you stuck in this > `But I haven't been able to find a way to use Flow to then process the merge between those two duplicate record items.`?